# Fourier Transform on a compact support

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, complex-integration, fourier-transform

Is there a Fourier Transform of a function that exists only on an interval like [0,1]? A solution might be to use a window function, that’s what others told me. But that’s not what I want. My concrete problem is: I use a fourier-series because my function is 2$\pi$ -periodic. In the next step, I just have subset of 2$\pi$, like [0,$\pi$]. I don’t know how or whether I can make a transformation of a function, that only exists on that angular range. It’s like "is there any Fourier transform on a compact carrier"?
Best regards
Loki

Comment: Yes there is the cardinal sine $sinc(t)=\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}$ or $\dfrac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$ or $\dfrac{\sin(k t)}{k t}$ with Fourier transform a rectangular pulse (characteristic function of an interval $[-a,a]$). Besides : compact "carrier" $\rightarrow$ compact "support."

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie, you’re right, compact support is what I meant. Maybe my question was ambigous the way I shaped it: My problem is not to find a specific function whos support is [0,1] and whose fouriertransform exists. My problem is more generell: I’m askin‘ myself wheather a function, that only exists on an subset of the real space (intervall/compact support/subset…I’m not really sure what’s the difference, I’m not a mathematician), can have a fouriertransformation? What do I have to concern, if I would like to know the spectrum of a function on a compact support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Fourier series on any interval $[a,b]$ by mapping the interval linearly to $[0,2\pi]$. For example, if you have a function $f$ defined on $[0,\pi]$, you can define a function $\tilde{f}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ by $\tilde{f}(x) = f(2x)$, expand it as a Fourier series (let us assume it converges) to obtain

$$ \tilde{f}(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{i n x} $$

but then

$$ f(x) = \tilde{f} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{\frac{i n x}{2}}. $$

You can also write a formula for the coefficients $a_n$ in terms of $f$ alone by performing a variable change and this generalizes to arbitrary intervals.

Comment: thanks for your help. I like your idea of mapping on the initial space. But how to make sure that the series converges? Do I have to assume steadiness and periodicity of f(x) or \tilde{f}? Is your mapping-approach „mathematically clean“ or are there any traps? Could you help me a second time?

Comment: Before you even map the interval, you must have some conditions of convergence for Fourier series (as there are, and in what sense do you mean as well?) performing a continuous transformation to $[0,2\pi]$ wouldn't change anything.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you work over $[0,2\pi]$ or $[0,1]$, if you want pointwise (or better) convergence, you need to assume some conditions on $f$. For example, if $f$ is $\pi$-periodic and continuously differentiable, then the Fourier series of $\tilde{f}$ will converge and so does our series for $f$.